# Conditionally replace levels of factor variable using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I know how to conditionally replace levels of a variable using dplyr/tidyr. Here's some toy data (the real dataset is much larger and more complex):

```
dat <- data.frame(animal=c("cat", "cat", "dog", "cat"),
              size=c("big", "big", "big", "small"))

 newdata <- dat %>% mutate(newanimal=replace(animal, animal=='cat' & size=='big', "fatcat"))
```

And I keep getting "invalid factor level, NA generated" - why?! These are factor variables, the specific combination of 'cat' and 'big' exists in the dataframe. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Just do `dat %>% mutate(newanimal=replace(animal, animal=='cat' & size=='big', "fatcat"))`

Comment: I already did that and I get the same error about invalid factor level.

Comment: One question. You are using `filter` here. After the substitution, you want the whole table or just the filtered columns?

Comment: run your code, it's not reproducible! `as_data_frame` doesn't work like this.

Comment: Aren't you replacing with a level that isn't already in the data, i.e. "fatcat"? Factors lock in their levels, you have to add a level specifically to what's allowable. You've also got problems with your example: setting up a data frame that way, at least with recent versions of dplyr, makes a data frame with a single column, so I get an error with the `colnames` call. Just set the names while creating the data frame. Also in this example, you don't actually have any factors

Comment: Also, `as_data_frame` is deprecated in favor of `as_tibble`. But to create a data frame, call `tibble` or `data.frame` directly

Comment: I would like the whole dataframe, just with this specific level changed to "fatcat"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @camille mentioned, once you have a factor, it's locked in, and if you introduce new "entries", it becomes NA.

For example:

```
x <- factor(letters[1:3])
x[3] = "d"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 3, value = "d") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
x
[1] a    b    <NA>
Levels: a b c
```

The only way to get out of this, is to convert it to character first and replace:

```
newdata <- dat %>% mutate(newanimal=replace(as.character(animal), animal=='cat' & size=='big', "fatcat"))
newdata
  animal  size newanimal
1    cat   big    fatcat
2    cat   big    fatcat
3    dog   big       dog
4    cat small       cat
```

Your new column is a character now, but you can always convert it back to a factor, if you need that..

```
str(newdata)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ animal   : Factor w/ 2 levels "cat","dog": 1 1 2 1
 $ size     : Factor w/ 2 levels "big","small": 1 1 1 2
 $ newanimal: chr  "fatcat" "fatcat" "dog" "cat"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option in the tidyverse is to use `forcats::fct_expand` to add the new level and then pipe this vector into the original `replace` which will now work as expected. The new variable is a factor and no further conversion is necessary (given that your desired output is a factor).

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(newanimal = fct_expand(animal, "fatcat") %>% 
                     replace(., animal == "cat" & size == "big", "fatcat")
         ) 

glimpse(dat)
Observations: 4
Variables: 3
$ animal    <fct> cat, cat, dog, cat
$ size      <fct> big, big, big, small
$ newanimal <fct> fatcat, fatcat, dog, cat
```

If you use this kind of factor replacement a lot, you could write your own helper function:

```
replace_fct <- function(x, list, values) {

  .x = forcats::fct_expand(x, unique(values))
  replace(.x, list, values)

}
```

And then do:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(newanimal = replace_fct(animal, animal == "cat" & size == "big", "fatcat")
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(animal = c("cat","dog","cat","dog","dog","dog"), 
             size =  c("big", "small", "big", "big", "big","big"))

dat %>% mutate(new_animal = ifelse(animal=='cat' & size=='big','fatcat',animal) ) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
```

Comment: This almost worked - why does my else condition fill in with an integer though? (i.e. "dog" becomes 1.

Comment: because it is the index of the factor. You should do this before having your data as factors but when they are characters